# Can a non trivial definition of truth be given?

Tags: analytic-philosophy

Would it be provable that it can or cannot be given? What literature would you recommend me for looking into various theories of truth? Thanks.

Comment: You can find a good overview of the subject in *Theories of Truth: A Critical Introduction* by Richard Kirkham.

Comment: "Deflationary Truth" is a collection of many of the most important papers on this topic.  https://books.google.com/books/about/Deflationary_Truth.html?id=MGdBkgEACAAJ

Comment: The problem is not with giving such a definition, but that [there are too many given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth#Major_theories), all of them controversial. Look also at Tarski's undefinability theorem, stated and proved by Alfred [Tarski's undefinability of truth theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_undefinability_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) which roughly states that the notion of truth in a *first order* language (consistent and containing arithmetic) can not be defined within it.

Answer (score 2):

Which sense of trivial? In the non-pejorative sense, truth is trivial, mundane, quotidian. Truth is merely a condition of propositions satisfied when what is said is corresponds with (matches, fits, etc.) what is. See [chapter 9](http://epistemh.pbworks.com/f/6.+The+Construction+of+Social+Reality+(SCAN).pdf) for Searle's presentation and defense of the correspondence theory of truth.

Also, see [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/39737/william-james-definition-of-truth-and-rightheousness/39738#39738) for references to the works of William James's "pragmatic" approach to truth.